# Git folder name change locally not pushing to remote

Tags: git, github

I've got an issue where I've renamed a folder locally, and changed the folder name to start with a lower case rather than an upper case. I can see the change in my local, and I've made another code change as well. I've pushed it to my Github repo branch by doing the following:

1. `git add .`
2. `git commit -m "commit message"`
3. `git push origin HEAD:feature_branch_name`

I can see the code change in the latest commit, but for some reason, my folder name is not the same (in my remote branch, the folder name still starts with an upper case).

I know this is a very broad question that is hard to reproduce, but is there any reason this may be the case?

I can't even do `git mv <old name> <new name>` in my terminal because the folder name in my local is what the folder name in the remote branch should be.

Comment: This task is *far* easier if you use a file system (and/or entire OS) that *doesn't* treat files named `README.md` and `ReadMe.md` as *the same* file. If you're on a Mac, create a case-sensitive disk image and do the work in a clone made in that location, or use VirtualBox or similar to bring up a Linux system and do the work in the VM.

Comment: Thank you. Not going to lie, I think your above solution would be fine for a large project. Mine is quite small so I've done what i've explained in the below answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the folder name by creating a temporary folder ?

```
git mv <old-name> temp
git mv temp <new-name>

# Commit and Push the changes
```

> I can't even do `git mv <old name> <new name>` in my terminal because
>   the folder name in my local is what the folder name in the remote
>   branch should be.

Clone the repo again and try doing the above.

Comment: Thank you. What I have decided to do was to remove the folder in question, then push after having deleted it. Then I readded the folder locally, and repushed, and that solved it. Probably not the cleanest of ways to resolve the issue, but seeing as how it was only a couple of folders that had this issue, it turned out to be fine.

Answer (score -1):

Make a copy of your full App in other folder then delete the holder App from that folder and push it empty, then paste the copied App back again and Push, it will work then.